# Maximum number of queries in a Redis multi/exec request

Tags: redis, node-redis

Is there a limit to how many queries one could send when using multi/exec from a node-redis application or is it only a question of available memory on the client and server to buffer requests and replies?

Answer (score 4):

It's only a question of available memory.

Firstly on the client side as node-redis will queue up the queries you do on the multi and not send any of them to Redis before the exec is executed.

And secondly on the Redis server as it needs to be able to hold all the queries and answers at once as it is an atomic operation.